# regex and javascript, some matches disappear !

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the code :

```
> var reg = new RegExp(" hel.lo ", 'g');
> 
> var str = " helalo helblo helclo heldlo ";
> 
> var mat = str.match(reg);
> 
> alert(mat);
```

It alerts "helalo, helclo", but i expect it to be "helalo, helblo, helclo, heldlo" . 
Only the half of them matches, I guess that's because of the space wich count only once. So I tried to double every space before processing, but in some case it's not enough.
I'm looking for an explanation, and a solution.

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  "␣helalo␣helblo␣helclo␣heldlo␣"
// 11111111------22222222-------
```

When `␣helalo␣` was matched, the string left is `helblo␣...` *without the leading space*. But the regex requires a leading space, so it skips to `␣helclo␣`.

To avoid the expression eating up the space, use a lookahead.

```
var reg = / hel.lo(?= )/g
```

(Or use `\b` as a word boundary.)

Comment: +1 in general, but the //11111111------22222222------- visualisation is very helpful for those first starting out in the painful world of regex!

Answer (score 1):

It matches the regex, advances to the next character after the matched string and goes on.

You can use `\b` to match word boundaries. You can add the whitespaces later, if you want to.

```
\bhel.lo\b
```

Comment: the matter wuth the \b is that it will match for example ' :helalo: '